# Existence of a null sequence that dominates an infinite family of null sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Let us call $a =(a_n)_{n \geq 0}$ a $\textit{null sequence }$ if $a_n \geq 0$ for all $n \geq 0$ and $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} a_n =0$.

For two null sequences $a$ and $b$, we say that $a$ dominates $b$ if there exists $n_0$ such that $a_n \geq b_n$ for all $n \geq n_0$.

Given an infinite family of null sequences $(a^{(i)})_{i \in \mathbb{N}}$, is there a null sequence $a$ that dominates $a^{(i)}$ for all $i \in \mathbb{N}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Choose positive integers $N_1\lt N_2\lt N_3\lt\cdots$ so that
$$\max\left(a^{(1)}_n,a^{(2)}_n,a^{(3)}_n,\dots,a^{(i)}_n\right)\le\frac1i\text{ for all }n\ge N_i.$$
Define a sequence $b=(b_n)$ so that $b_n=\frac1i$ when $N_i\le n\lt N_{i+1}$. You can easily verify that $b$ is a null sequence which dominates each of the given null sequences.